# Disable "constrained" or set default layout:type: to "default"?

Tags: wordpress

i wanna change an default attribute of the core/group block in wordpress.

By default, the block "core/group" will always created with an layout styling which is called "constrained" and it will add css classes to the block.

```
"wp-block-group is-layout-constrained wp-block-group-is-layout-constrained"
```

This class "is-layout-constrained" wrap the content in a max-width container.

We are able to disbale these setting in the block settings. When turn off, the class will change from "is-layout-constrained" to "is-layout-flow"

```
wp-block-group is-layout-flow wp-block-group-is-layout-flow
```

Is it possible to set the default class to "is-layout-flow" when create a core/group?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do this by adding:

```
add_theme_support( 'disable-layout-styles' );
```

to your functions.php or your plugin.

Comment: This doesn't remove the classes, just the CSS generated to go with the classes.